# How to define a subclass of ListBlock with fixed contents?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Is there a better way than this to make a subclass of `ListBlock` with fixed contents?

```
class MixedMediaCarouselBlock(blocks.ListBlock):
    """
    A hghly streamlined CarouselBlock which displays only Images and/or Videos.
    """

    def __init__(self, child_block=None, **kwargs):
        child_block = blocks.StructBlock([
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=False)),
            ('video', EmbedBlock(
                label="Video URL",
                help_text="Paste the video URL from YouTube or Vimeo."
                          " e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Pz_xQZVDg"
                          " or https://vimeo.com/207076450.",
                required=False
                )
            ),
        ])
        super(MixedMediaCarouselBlock, self).__init__(child_block, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        template = 'core/blocks/mixed_media_carousel_block.html'
        label = 'Mixed Media Carousel'
        icon = 'media'
```

It feels really hacky to do it this way, but I can't find any other obvious method, because `ListBlock` requires that `child_block` argument to its constructor, while other block types do not.

The reason I want a `ListBlock` subclass is to use it as the single block type in a `StreamField` in one of my Pages:

```
class News(Page)
    assets = StreamField(
        MixedMediaCarouselBlock(), 
        help_text='Pick one or more images/videos to place in the sidebar of this article.'
    )
```

Maybe I'm just doing this wrong?

EDIT: Yup, I'm definitely doing something wrong. This doesn't work at all, as I just discovered when I tried to save a Page with this setup and got `AttributeError: 'MixedMediaCarouselBlock' object has no attribute 'child_blocks'` on wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py line 401. (Wagtail 1.12.2). No idea why, though.

EDIT2: I followed @gasman's advice, and came up with this:

```
class MixedMediaCarouselBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    slides = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock([
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=False)),
            ('video', EmbedBlock(
                label="Video URL",
                help_text="Paste the video URL from YouTube or Vimeo."
                          " e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Pz_xQZVDg or https://vimeo.com/207076450.",
                required=False
                )
            ),
        ])
    )
```

But I still get a block type menu on the page edit form (I'm using wagtail-facelift):

[image: Block Type Menu]

Worse still, the form lets me add multiple instances of `slides` to the StreamField, which could easily lead to users accidentally making multiple single-elements ListBlocks, instead of one multi-element ListBlock, which would break the renderer. What can I do about this?

EDIT3: This is what I came up with after much experimentation, but I don't love it at all.

```
class MixedMediaCarouselBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """
    A hghly streamlined CarouselBlock which displays only Images and/or Videos.
    """

    slides = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock([
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=False)),
            ('video', EmbedBlock(
                label="Video URL",
                help_text="Paste the video URL from YouTube or Vimeo."
                          " e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Pz_xQZVDg or https://vimeo.com/207076450.",
                required=False
                )
            ),
        ])
    )

    class Meta:
        template = 'core/blocks/mixed_media_carousel_block.html'
        label = 'Mixed Media Carousel'
        icon = 'media'

class News(Page):
    ...
    assets = StreamField(
        ('media', MixedMediaCarouselBlock()),
        help_text='Pick one or more images/videos to place in the sidebar of this article.'
    )
```

Then, to handle the problem of users accidentally adding multiple `MixedMediaCarouselBlock`s instead of multiple videos/images within a single `MixedMediaCarouselBlock`, I hacked up some LESS CSS to hide the UI that would let them do that:

```
body.model-news {
  .stream-menu .toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .sequence-controls:not(.list-controls) button[id$=delete] {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

During my R&D, I ran across the Wagtail 1.12 patch notes, which mention the addition of the `min_num`, `max_num`, and `block_counts` meta attrs to `StreamBlock`, which sounded really promising. But they don't affect the UI; they just add server-side validation that makes invalid choices show up as form errors after POSTing. If they prevented invalid changes from being made in the first place, I could actually use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your block definition is correct, as far as I can see. ListBlock wasn't designed to be subclassed, so trying to do so is inevitably going to be a bit hacky and not guaranteed to be stable across Wagtail releases - but you're not relying on any of the internals of ListBlock, only altering the constructor's method signature, so it should be safe enough. Bear in mind that if you subclass any block other than StructBlock, StreamBlock or ChoiceBlock, references to your subclass will appear in migration files, and so it's your responsibility to keep the class definition in place for as long as those migrations exist: see http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.2/topics/streamfield.html#streamfield-definitions-within-migrations.

The problem here is that StreamBlock (and subclasses) is currently the only block type allowed as the top-level block of a StreamField: allowing other block types has been proposed ([#2048](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2048.)) but hasn't been implemented yet. As a workaround, you could define MixedMediaCarouselBlock as a StreamBlock with only one child block type; this isn't as clunky as it might sound, because in this situation the menu for choosing a block type is skipped ([#1696](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/1696)), which makes the behaviour more or less the same as a ListBlock.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Though I'm not quite getting the behavior you described. Perhaps I designed my updated `MixedMediaCarouselBlock` wrong? I've added it, and the problem I'm still having, to the original question.

Comment: The idea of using StreamBlock is that you'd make the StructBlock the one and only child of it, and leave out the ListBlock layer. I'll have to re-familiarise myself with how single-child StreamBlocks work, then - I think it may be that the menu shows on the initial empty state, but not when subsequently clicking the 'add' button.

Comment: Well, that would work... but the UI for "add block" is significantly less pretty than the UI for "add another `ListBlock` element". But that may be the best solution, in the face of `ListBlock` not being usable as a top-level block.

If you want, check out my "EDIT3". I found a way to make this work, but it's hacky enough that I may go with your solution instead.